# Xcode's "rebase local changes onto upstream changes"?

Tags: xcode, git

What "rebase local changes onto upstream changes" in Pull menu option mean?
Can it possibly anyhow change remote branches?

Comment: With that name, I guess it's a `rebase` options of `git`.

Comment: I usually use `cmmd + option + c` to see the diff. But I was accidentally hitting `cmmd + option + x` and wondered what it was...

Comment: If it's `git pull --rebase`, then it can't change remote branches.

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like it is doing `git pull --rebase` (vs just `git pull`).

Consider this:
remote origin/master has commits: c1 -> c2 -> **c3**
and your local master looks like: c1 -> c2 -> **c4**

If you don't use "Rebase" option, Pull will **merge** `c3` into your `c4` commit.
With "Rebase" - Pull will first copy `c3` to your local master and keep `c4` clean and on top: c1 -> c2 -> c3 -> **c4**

In this example I believe "rebase local changes onto upstream changes" should be preferred.

Comment: Whether the "Rebase" option is selected or not, there is a prompt to "Stash Changes" which has it's own option to "Apply Stash After Operation" - is this a redundant operation?

Comment: @samus : "Stash Changes" popup only appears if you are trying to **pull** AND you have uncommitted changes. So, it practically asks you what do you want to do with those locally modified files. Stash saves your local uncommitted modifications away and reverts the working directory to the clean state, before your uncommitted changes. In previous Xcode versions it would force you to commit before pull.

Comment: Oh right, commit doesn't push or pull.

Comment: @DimaG You can stash changes manually at any time using Stash Changes item from Source Control menu. Then you can manage and apply your stashes in Source Control navigator panel under Repositories tab. Useful for many things, not just helping you with pulling.

Comment: Of course, stash has its use cases, but the original question is specifically about "rebase", so I try to stay on-topic :)